# How do I add a field to the sign_up form in Rails Devise, but not the User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There are several answers out there on how to add a field to the sign_up form in Rails 4 if the field is also a new property of the User model. But how do I add a field to the sign_up form that is not a part of the User model? In my specific example, I would like to add a Company Name field in the sign up form, which would then be used to create a Company model before the User model is created. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What happened when you just tried adding the field to the form as a field_tag and looked at what came through in the params? :)

Comment: First, do you have a User custom controller?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the response.

The answer was as simple as running the following to generate the devise controllers:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Then updating the route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Adding a form_tag to the form:

```
<%= text_field_tag("company_name", nil, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

Then updating the method in the registrations controller to create the company:

```
# POST /resource
def create
super do |resource|
  company_name = params[:company_name]
  company = Company.new({name: company_name})
  company.save!
end
```

end

Comment: In my case - I do not care if the company exists or not. But if I did, I suppose I could do something like: Company.find_or_create_by(name: params[:company_name]);